# CodeIgniter email validation

Tags: codeigniter

I want to validate an input field with an email address.

If I use

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]');
```

If I enter same examples into the field to test the validation the result is...

"test" = failed

"test@" = failed

"test@test" = not failed

In this example I have a value which is not formatted correctly with email-syntax, but the validation accepts it. An email address of test@test should not pass validation.

What do I have to do so that the form-validation of codeigniter will check for a correctly formatted email syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes This was also the case with me. Eventually i created callback function to validate email and that worked like charm.

```
function validateEmail($email) {
    if (preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-+]+(\.[_a-z0-9-+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/", $email)) {
    return true;  
    }
    return false;
}
```

Add callback function in your validation rules

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|is_unique[users.email]|callback_validateEmail');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Additionally you can add this code to a my form validation class in libraries and the function will be available globally without prepending `callback` or adding it to every controller where you need it.